# Импорт .swf файла целиком в Haxe OpenFL

Tags: flash, haxe, openfl

Здравстсвуйте! 

Нужно импортировать весь swf файл (а не только определенный класс) в Haxe (OpenFL) для дальнейшей обработки.
Исходный код swf файла неизвестен, но как я понял из офф. документации - он и не нужен. 
Мне нужен лишь пример рабочего кода, т.к. мой выдает ошибку "Null Object Reference" при компиляции. Заранее спасибо.

#### `Main.hx`

```
package;

import openfl.display.Bitmap;
import openfl.display.Sprite;
import openfl.Lib;
import openfl.Assets;

/**
 * ...
 * @author Ian Andrushchuk
 */
class Main extends Sprite 
{

    public function new() 
    {
        super();

        Assets.loadLibrary("274", function(_) {
            var clip = Assets.getMovieClip ("274:");
            addChild(clip);

            clip.x = 0;
            clip.y = 0;
        });
    }

}
```

#### `project.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project>

    <meta title="Основные элементы электрических схем" package="Основные элементы электрических схем" version="1.0.0" company="Ian Andrushchuk" />

    <app main="Main" file="Основные элементы электрических схем" path="bin" />

    <window background="#000000" fps="60" />
    <window width="800" height="480" unless="mobile" />
    <window orientation="landscape" vsync="false" antialiasing="0" if="cpp" />

    <source path="src" />
    <haxelib name="openfl" />
    <haxelib name="actuate" />
    <haxelib name="swf" />
    <library path="Assets/img/274.swf" />

    <icon path="assets/openfl.svg" />
    <assets path="assets/img" rename="img" />

</project>
```

Comment: Добавьте свой код, возможно это больше понять Вашу проблему и помочь Вам

Comment: http://community.openfl.org/t/importing-whole-swf-maybe-as2/8519